# Advanced Search: Proximity search fails; returns "We could not geocode the destination address."

Tags: search

Side Note: This worked before upgrading from 4.7.8 to 4.7.10.

When we go to Advanced Search (ourdomain/civicrm/contact/search/advanced): Address Fields, enter a Postal Code and a range (ex: Find contacts within 25 miles), and click "Search," CiviCRM returns an error like:

No matches found for:
Proximity search to a distance of 20 miles from 78660, UNITED STATES: We could not geocode the destination address.

I went to the sandbox (http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/advanced ) to check/test this, but the sandbox does not offer the option to search by proximity to a Postal Code. The sandbox is running 4.7.11

Thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proximity search worked fine for me in 4.7.11 and 4.7.10.  Proximity search is available on the demo if you select a geocoding provider (**Administer menu » System Settings » Mapping and Geocoding**).

I'd advise checking/changing your system's geocoding settings.  If that doesn't work, please update the question with the settings that aren't working, this is likely specific to your settings.

Comment: Well paint me red and call me a cherry. I feel like a proper fool for not realizing the cause. Silly me!

Thank you for the tip. You were 100% correct. I selected Google as our geocoder and it's working correctly now.

Comment: Clearing the settings and re-selecting them worked for me after upgrade to 4.6.26, cleared the existing settings, saved, then re-selected Google and saved again. No Key needed for google :)